# Preventing BOTS on Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a WEB API 2 running on production using `GET` method. However when I see the log, something was trying to access the API with `OPTIONS` method. Of course it will get an `Error 404`.

This is become annoying when it's trying to access the API 2 or 3 times a day. I know I can just allow `[HttpOptions]` method, but is there any another way to preventing a BOTS?

This is my public API:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/v1/customer/info/{EmailId}")]
public async Task<MyModel> getCustomerData(string EmailId)
{
...//some function
}
```

Comment: There is nothing you can do in C# code to prevent external callers to access you public IP. Depending on your scale ServerFault.com or webmasters.stackexchange.com may be better place to ask question if you are looking for traffic filtering.

Comment: Side note: you may want to clarify your definition of "bot"... Some people may assume "search bot" (like Google bot) which probably not what you mean.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov actually I get this from Google Analytic, was checked from log request. so maybe it's from Google BOT too?

Comment: You should look at your server logs of incoming requests - you'll see referrer/user agent for each which likely explain what site/tool called your service.